# How to detect current internet speed of different devices connected to WiFi?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, android

Is there any way to detect how much bandwidth different devices are currently consuming? suppose there are 3 android devices and 2 laptops are connected. I would like to know individual breakup of current internet speed of these 5 devices.

example for better explanation:

```
+-------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
|    MAC ADDRESS    | Current Download Speed | Current Upload Speed |
+-------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
| 10-F0-05-09-51-C1 | 2 MB/s                 | 0.1 MB/s             |
| 20-F0-05-09-51-C2 | 2.4 MB/s               | 0.9 MB/s             |
| 30-F0-05-09-51-C3 | 0.4 MB/s               | 0 MB/s               |
| 40-F0-05-09-51-C4 | 0 MB/s                 | 0 MB/s               |
| 50-F0-05-09-51-C5 | 0 MB/s                 | 0 MB/s               |
+-------------------+------------------------+----------------------+
```

This is for my home network so I am connected to WiFi and have router access.

Tools I have: Android (Rooted), Windows 10.

Comment: Asking for program recommendations is off topic here, as is questions about Android. Questions about your home network ARE on topic, but you need to edit your question to remove the requests for recommendations and to focus on what you're actually asking for.

Comment: @music2myear thanks for pointing out, I've updated the question to better suit the community guidelines

Comment: This would be doable with an appropriate router - which is where the measurements would need to take place.

Comment: if router doesn't support it then can't it be done using some command line tool like wireshark etc